# Variable length array; Another construct MSVC isn't able to compile?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

After I read ISO:IEC 9899:TC3 6.7.5.2 Array declarators -> 10 EXAMPLE 4.
I was wondering that I never have seen code with such kind of usefull construct before.

I wrote this simple sample code to test I got it right how its working.

```
int m = 9;

int foo (int iArray[m], int n);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int iArray[m];
    int n = 5;

    iArray[n] = 555;
    printf ("%d\r\n", foo (iArray, n));

    return 0;
}

int foo (int iArray[m], int n)
{
    int iLocalArray[n];

    iLocalArray[n - 1] = iArray[n];

    return iLocalArray[n - 1];
}
```

When I tryed to compile this code on MSVC2010.... Of course it wasn't able to compile.
As we know there isn't any real C microsoft compiler up to MSVC2013.
But well so I installed the MSVC2013RC and thought, there should it run as they say MSVC2013 includes a real C99 compiler. When I started compiling, still the same errors:

```
1>[...].c(6): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>[...].c(6): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>[...].c(11): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>[...].c(11): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>[...].c(11): error C2133: 'iArray' : unknown size
1>[...].c(20): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>[...].c(20): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>[...].c(22): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>[...].c(22): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>[...].c(22): error C2133: 'iLocalArray' : unknown size
```

But this are quite strange errors for a compiler which is announced as the first microsoft compiler who respects even the C99 standard, isn't it? Or I'm just getting the usage of variable length arrays wrong and use a wrong syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the MSVC documentation (which is subject to change) then it states that [MSVC 2013 conforms to C90](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02y9a5ye%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) and the [reference for declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5eay31s2%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) does not mention VLAs. There is also a [roadmap for MSVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/28/cpp-conformance-roadmap.aspx) that says they are taking tactical elements of C99, so not necessarily supporting the full standard.

Therefore it appears that VLAs are still not part of the supported subset of C99 in MSVC 2013.

Comment: Ah so I'm sorry about, I just noticed that they took in `_Bool` so I thought they are upgrading to finally use c99. Sad that this is still not the case. Just by the way, do you know about MSVC13 allows variable declarations after asignments?

Comment: @Zaibis: It is not allowed, according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce4b8s02%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) 'If there are declarations, they must come before any statements.' However I do not have the compiler here to test.

Comment: Just checked it by my self. MSVC2013 allows variable declarations after statements have already been invoked.